# add element/class to a first unique word from a string in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to insert a tag from the first unique word from a string using javascript / jquery. It is something like:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(".product_title:contains(NEW)").replace('NEW', '<span class="new">NEW</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
FROM: <h2 class="product_title">NEW Jeep Wrangler</h2>
INTO: <h2 class="product_title"><span class="new">NEW</span>Jeep Wrangler</h2>
FROM: <h2 class="product_title">REBUILT Jeep Wrangler</h2>
INTO: <h2 class="product_title"><span class="rebuilt">REBUILT</span>Jeep Wrangler</h2>
```

I tried below approach to replace the first word with html code but didn't work: I received a `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).replace is not a function` on console.

How to achieve this? I can't find any examples on the web that is applying this similar approach. Please advise.

UPDATE: I think I'm close, I use below approach:

```
$('.product_title').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('NEW', '<span class="cust-woo-title-tag-new">NEW</span>')); 
});
```

But the tags are displaying on the front end.

Comment: Can you also mention what you already tried? It would be much easier to help that way. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what a 'first unique word' is? At first I thought it meant to look at the string and decide which words were unique (ie only one of them in that string) and then pick the first one, but then your examples only pick the first word. Are you doing this so you can style it differently?

Comment: @deepakchethan , yes, please see updated.

Comment: @A Haworth, yes thats correct. i want to style the first words differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. get all the product_title that contains "NEW"
2. store the previous html value (eg. `NEW Jeep Wrangler`)
3. remove the "NEW" word (`NEW Jeep Wrangler` becomes Jeep Wrangler)
4. update the `innerHTML`

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function($){
      //get all the product_title that contains "NEW"
      let contains_new = $(".product_title:contains(NEW)");
      
      for(let x = 0; x < contains_new.length; x++) {
         //store the previous html value
         let prev_html = contains_new[x].innerHTML;
         
         //remove the "NEW" word in the prev_html
         let new_html = prev_html.replace('NEW','');
         
         //update the inner html
         contains_new[x].innerHTML = `<span class"new">NEW</span>${new_html}`;
      }
   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <h2 class="product_title">NEW Jeep Wrangler</h2>
   <h2 class="product_title">NEW Jeep Wrangler</h2>
   ```

*try to inspect element the result to view the `html` structure.*

Comment: Thanks. This works. I found out that my code also works by changing .text() to .html() like:

`$(this).html(text.replace('NEW', '<span class="new">NEW</span>')); `

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```js
$('h2').each((i)=>{
 txt=$(i).text().split(' ')
i_html = `
<span class ='${txt[0]}.toLocaleLowerCase()' >${txt.pop(0)}</span> ${txt.join(' ')}
`
$(i).html(i_html)
})
```

If you just want to do it for certain words, create a array with them and check with `keywords.include(txt[0])`